# Deploy a GWT app within IIS 7

Tags: iis, cache

I am currently trying to configure an ASP.net Web Application through Web.config, to host a GWT WebApp in a specific folder. I've managed to configure the mimeMap for the .manifest file extension in the system.Webserver/staticContent section however, i'm stuck with the clientCache. I want to add a caching rule so that files with ".nocache." are served with the following headers:

```
"Expires", "Sat, 21 Jan 2012 12:12:02 GMT" (today -1);
"Pragma", "no-cache"
"Cache-control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"
```

Anyone knows how to do this within IIS 7+ ?

Answer (score 0):

ended up creating a custom httphandler to handle all the requests to the path .nocache. using a solution similar to the one described in here:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5063338/prevent-scripts-from-being-cached-programmatically